# Stuck with solving inequality to find the product of highest and lowest integer solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The inequality in question is
$$\sqrt{(5+2\sqrt{6})^{2x}}+\sqrt{(5-2\sqrt{6})^{2x}}\leq98$$
This time our job is to find the product of highest and lowest integer solutions.

---

*My attempt*

$$\sqrt{(5+2\sqrt{6})^{2x}}+\sqrt{(5-2\sqrt{6})^{2x}}\leq98$$
$$\sqrt{((5+2\sqrt{6})^{x})^2}+\sqrt{((5-2\sqrt{6})^{x})^2}\leq98$$
$$(5+2\sqrt{6})^x+(5-2\sqrt{6})^x\leq98$$
What next?

---

The solution is $-4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $(5+2\sqrt6)(5-2\sqrt6)=1$

if $(5+2\sqrt6)^x=a>0$

$$a+\dfrac1a\le98\iff a^2-98a+1\le0$$

$a^2-98a+1=0\implies a=\dfrac{98\pm40\sqrt6}2=49\pm20\sqrt6=(5\pm2\sqrt6)^2$

$\implies(5+2\sqrt6)^{-2}=(5-2\sqrt6)^2\le a\le(5+2\sqrt6)^2 $

$\implies-2\le x\le2$

Comment: I think you should use $a$ instead of $t$ for consistency.

Comment: @Vuk, Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$
(a+b)^2+(a-b)^2= 2a^2+2b^2 = 98
$$

with $a = 5$ and $b = 2\sqrt 6$